# (Reasonably) accurate 1Hz clock generator

Tags: clock, flipflop, battery-operated

I would like your advice on components before I purchase anything.

I am going to make a digital 24hr clock using probably JK flip flops/multiplexors with 7 segment displays. But it must be battery-operated.

Is using a 32kHz quartz crystal, a good way of producing a 1Hz clock signal for my FF's? I know I will have to do some frequency division (2^15) with FF's.

If so, is there an IC I can buy that produces a 1Hz output signal? If anyone knows any part numbers off the top of your head, it would be good if you could share them.

Does the quartz crystal require any other circuitry to operate?

I haven't used the mentioned component before, sorry if the questions are silly.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure it's a 32.768kHz crystal and not a 32.0kHz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Is using a quartz crystal 32kHz a good way of producing a 1Hz clock signal for my FF's*

Yes, that is the way to do that. You probably haven't met the [4060](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/HEF4060B.pdf) CMOS logic chip yet because it can do most of what you need.

Look at page 8 for how it can use a Crystal as the input clock. It will divide down that clock with a series of flip-flops by \$2^{14}\$ so you'll get 2 Hz form a 32768 Hz (watch) crystal. So add another divide-by-2 and you're done.

Comment: Ah, yes this seems like what I require. For my application, do you think I will need any other circuitry other then connecting to supply pins, crystal oscillator inputs and frequency output?

Comment: I suggest that you use Google to search for: "4060 circuit" to see how most circuits use it and do the same. Also the datasheet shows clear examples of what is needed. For example when using a crystal, there are always 2 small capacitors needed.

Comment: Put a small piece of copper foil ( 1 inch square) under the 32KHz xtal and the 2 in/out capacitors, and connect the foil to GND of the oscillator/divider IC. This helps with electric field interference.

Comment: And another confusing comment from analogsystemsrf. Just ignore it, adding shielding isn't needed and the risk of creating a short worries me much more than EMI. At 32 kHz EMI is rarely an issue especially at low power circuits like discussed here.

Answer (score 1):

If there are many ICs that produce your required 1 PPS (pulse per second) output from a 32kHz crystal. You will find them called “real time clock” (RTC).

Comment: These seem interesting thanks, will take a closer look...

Comment: The DS1307 is a nice example of this, you can get this chip on a PCB module from ebay etc. and it can be programmed to output a 1 Hz clock (maybe it does that already by default though). It might require a microcontroller to work properly though.

Comment: by the way, there are many rather cheap microcontrollers these days that integrate an RTC, which can be extremely helpful, because the microcontroller might save a lot of battery power by doing things that would be rather complicated without digital logic very easily and efficiently, e.g. knowing what to light up to display time.